# Pipe fires only 1 time even though its value changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a filter like so:

*.html*

```
     <div>
          <app-categories [categories]="categories" 
(categoriesChange)="filterByCategories($event)">
                    </app-categories>
     </div>



 <p-dataView
     [value]="userItemsService.userItemsChanged$ | async | categoryFilter:searchTerms">

               //code

        </p-dataView>
```

*.ts*

```
searchTerms: string[];

filterByCategories(searchTerms: string[]): void {
    this.searchTerms = searchTerms;
  }
```

This is the `app-categories` component

[image]

The issue here is `categoryFilter` fires only for 1st Category selection. After that, it won't fire again. Can you tell me why?

pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'categoryFilter'
})
export class CategoryFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(userItems: UserItemModel[], searchTerms: string[]): UserItemModel[] {

    if (!userItems) { return []; }

    if (!searchTerms) { return userItems; }

    return userItems.filter(ui => {
      return searchTerms.some(st => ui.item?.primaryCategory.name?.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(st.toLocaleLowerCase()));
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made `this.searchTerms` immutable and then all use cases are working fine.

```
 filterByCategories(searchTerms: string[]): void {
    this.searchTerms = [...searchTerms];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your async pipe:

```
     [value]="userItemsService.userItemsChanged$ | async | categoryFilter:searchTerms">
```

This will only update when `userItemsService.userItemsChanged$` changes - not when you update `searchTerms` through the UI.
You should make `searchItems` a subject in your component and emit a value in `filterByCategories`:

```
searchTerms$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
...
filterByCategories(searchTerms: string[]): void {
    this.searchTerms$.next(searchTerms);
}
```

The rest can be done directly in the template using `<ng-container>`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{userItems: userItemsChanged$ | async, searchTerms: searchTerms$ | async} as data">
  <div>{{ userItems | categoryFilter:searchTerms }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Another approach would be to have a filtered `userItemsChanged$` stream in your component:

```
this.userItemsChangedFiltered$ = this.searchTerms$.pipe(
  switchMap(searchTerms => userItemsChanged$.pipe(
    map(userItems => <apply filter logic here>)
  )
)
```

Comment: This is not correct. My issue was the array mutability issue. Please see my answer.